# MS Graph Client Library, Delete an UploadSession

Tags: .net

Using the Microsoft Graph Client Library 1.21.0, I have found examples of how to create an upload session.  But I can not find examples of how to use the library to delete an upload session.  Please advise.

```
    private UploadSession CreateUploadSession(string relativeName)
    {
        UploadSession uploadSession = null;

        try
        {
            uploadSession = Task.Run(() => Client.Drives[DriveId].Items[RootPathId]
                .ItemWithPath(relativeName)
                .CreateUploadSession()
                .Request()
                .PostAsync())
                .Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle(ex =>
            {
                if (ex is ServiceException && ((ServiceException)ex).IsMatch(GraphErrorCode.NameAlreadyExists.ToString()))
                {
                    // An upload session already exists.  Delete it and try again.

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        return uploadSession;
    }
```